# Separate the user input with semicolon javascript html

Tags: javascript, html

I am not javascript html php expert but I would like to study I just wanted to ask for advice Is it possible to make the user can enter single or Multiple input of email in textbox separated by ; using javascript just like in outlook,yahoo,email?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
email <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: I would suggest you to look for existing libraries such as https://github.com/pierresh/multiple-emails.js

Comment: First need to consider all requirements you have, the way it is now - pulling an external library for such simple task, looks like overhead.

Answer (score -1):

Just Enter the text and click in the text box emails are separated

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Jquery - input tags plugin example</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-tagsinput/1.3.6/jquery.tagsinput.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-tagsinput/1.3.6/jquery.tagsinput.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background: #337AB7">


    <div style="width: 500px; margin: 0px auto;">
        <h2 style="font-family:cursive;">Jquery - input tags plugin example</h2>
        <input name="tags" id="input-tags" style="width:500px !important" />
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#input-tags').tagsInput();
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: " I would like to study" implies, that he wants to know how to do this, and not how to implement a plugin doing it.